# how to insert into a stack using a pointer in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        stack<int> *s;
        s->push(1);
        cout << s->top();
}
```

I am trying to learn how to insert int a stack using a pointer but i am getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: Change `stack<int> *s;` to `stack<int> s;` and `s->` to `s.`. Pointers are an expert-only feature that is not necessary for normal user code.

Comment: Your pointer s is a pointer to data of type stack<int>, but the pointer is not initialized to a value. So, if you push data to the stack, the data will be added to some random memory location. Writing to random memory locations results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: The edit completely changed the question, making the answers below invalid (and puzzling to the readers). This is frowned upon -- don't do that.

Comment: Rolled back last edit because it invalidated the answers & the question.

Answer (score 4):

> I am getting a segmentation fault.

This is because you don't have a stack, only an *unassigned* pointer to stack, which des not point to anything. In order for `s` to point to stack, assign it a new stack

```
stack<int> *s = new stack<int>();
```

or make it a stack, not a pointer

```
stack<int> s;
```

and use dots in place of `->` operator.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use STL object allocated dynamically, you almost never need to do it.
2. Pointers in C++ come uninitialized, if you really want/need to use a STL object allocated on heap then you need to initialize it, eg: `stack<int>* s = new stack<int>()`
3. If you really, really need to allocate them on heap then use `std::unique_ptr` to avoid the need of managing memory directly.